# How to add bot in microsoft teams to automatically send meeting minutes after meeting?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I hope the idea is clear, this happens when every time the meeting will end, the bot will automatically send the meeting minutes like startTime/endTime to team group.

Comment: Yes, we can get the meeting minutes by using Graph API. Could you please have a look on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#example-1-get-basic-details).

Comment: Hi @Rama-MSFT, is there a way i can follow or do this in simple steps since i don't have much knowledge on how to create a bot in microsoft teams or how to implement the one you just shared. thank you so much

Comment: Hi @Helmz Shelmz, could you please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots) about bot in Microsoft Teams, you will get complete idea on bot.